# What is the purpose of this function's parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to use a validate js plugin for a form (contact form with no refresh). I found this code below, where its author uses `submitHandler` key to send e-mails via AJAX and PHP. As the value there is a function `function(form) { ... }`. Could You tell me what is the purpose of the `form` parameter inside `function(form)`? The author doesn't even use it inside that function.

**JS CODE:**

```
$().ready(function() {
// validate the comment form when it is submitted.

 $("#actualForm").validate({
focusInvalid: false,
onkeyup: true,
    rules: {
    // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
        name: "required",
        comment: "required",
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
    },

submitHandler: function(form) {   
            var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
            var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
            var comment = $('input[name="comment"]').val();
            var params = {
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "comment": comment,
            };

            console.log(data);debugger;
            $.ajax({
            url: 'email.php',
            data: params,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: json,
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.status) {
                    //Give success log to user
                } else {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
            });
        }
```

Comment: It’s passing the form to the submit handler - for example to submit the DOM form if the AJAX validation passed

Comment: Looks like you’re supposed to fill out the `if` and `else` cases and _may_ use `form` there somehow.

Comment: Well what you showed it is not used so.... normally it is a reference to the form connected with the submit button so you can reference it.

Comment: It's probably there to provide some kind of context.  What if you have more than one form with an "email" field?  It would be much safer to use `$('input[name="email"]', form).val();` in theory.

Comment: SubmitHandler pass the object form like if you add `<form onsubmit="SubmitHandler(this);" ..>` with all of his childs (inputs, textarea, select ...) you can take from him what you want : for example : `form.elements['email'].value = "myemail@etc.com"`

Comment: Thanks @headmax , I hope You are right.